# How can I get an enum name from the name of the enum type and an int

Tags: c#, enums

From another layer in an application I can get back the name of the enum type and an integer value. How can I use this data to get the string representation of that value for that enum.

For example, if I have an enum:

```
public enum Cheese
{
    Edam = 1,
    Cheddar = 3,
    Brie = 201,
    RedLeicester = 1001
}
```

and the data I have available is

```
string dataType = "Cheese";
int dataValue = 3;
```

How can I get the result:

```
"Cheddar"
```

Comment: there are plenty of examples on how to return / get the name of an enum on the internet.. have you executed a fruitful search..?

Comment: Most of the results I get assume you have the type of the enum at compile time - which in this case, I don't

Comment: You'd have to use reflection to get the `Cheese` enum and its values, then

Comment: string name = ((Cheese)1).ToString();

Comment: The `Enum` class has static helper methods that take a `Type` parameter, ie: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getname(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: MethodMan : Doesn't it take the same amount of time to give the answer then to tell the person to search the web.  Your response is useless.  It took me 15 seconds to give a good answer.

Comment: @jdweng, so I guess that we should just give everyone the answer to any and all questions that are posted here..if that's the case then why should any of us be programmers / developers ... when we can just rely on others to do the work for us..? ???

Comment: The problem is beginners don't know enough to even figure out what to use to search the web.  Even experience people don't always know the key words to find the info on the web.  Giving a stupid answer like post code where beginners don't have have code and then when they post stupid code giving them negative points does nothing fruitful.

Comment: @jdweng It took you 15s to give half an answer. You failed to understand the question though. The other half, the part that you did not address, is how to obtain a type from its name. The asker could easily have done a websearch to find out how to do both of these. Of course experts can answer more quickly than a novice can search. So what? This question is trivially solved by websearch. If the asker is incapable of searching for this, then they are not up to being a programmer. It's a dupe many times over. Close it as such.

Comment: Again David you are wrong.  The OPs simple wanted to get the string from the number.

Comment: @jdweng Read carefully. Or even read at all. The enum type is not known at compile time. The accepted answer should make it clear to you. I know that you don't like being corrected, but don't let pride get in the way of reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to the name of enum itself you should know namespace and assembly that enum is declared at. Assuming you run code below in assembly where enum is defined and all your enums are defined in the same namespace you know at compile time, you can do it like that:

```
string dataType = "Cheese";
int dataValue = 3;
var enumType = Type.GetType("Namespaces.Of.Your.Enums." + dataType);
var name = Enum.GetName(enumType, dataValue);
```

If your enum is in another assembly than this code is running at - you will need to provide assembly qualified name of your enum type (again with namespace).

Answer (score 4):

```
Type t = Type.GetType(dataType)
string value = Enum.GetName(t, dataValue)
```

should do the trick (uncompiled, on subway)

Comment: This assumes you have an instance of the type in a variable dataType. In my situation I only have the string "Cheese" so Type would be string. Getting the type of the actual enum is the part of the process I'm missing.

Comment: No, Type.GetType gets a type from a type name. See @Evk answer for more elaborate explanation. You need to add namespace to the type name, if any.

Comment: Ah yes - qualifying the type name is what's required for this - I think I misread that as using dataType.GetType() for some reason!  My bad.

Answer (score 0):

enum.Parse() would be your friend here.

Like so:

```
int cheeseType = 1;
(Cheese)Enum.Parse(typeof(Cheese), cheeseType.ToString());
```

Comment: This assumes you have Cheese as a type at compile time. in my situation "Cheese" is a string. It's the reflection to get the type that I'm missing

Comment: This won't work. You only have the name of the `Cheese` type, not the type itself.

Comment: Gah you're right I missed that point